# Trying to do a simple Jump

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to learn how to make a 2D Game without Game Engines, anyways I already created a background scrolling right now my goal is to make my character jump. But the thing is whenever I start my app the character is spinning up and down and it will just go away to the background.

Here's my character code

```
public class Deer extends GameCharacter {

private Bitmap spritesheet;
private double dya;
private boolean playing;
private long startTime;
private boolean Jump;
private Animate Animation = new Animate();

public Deer(Bitmap res, int w, int h, int numFrames) {

    x = 20;
    y = 400;
    dy = 0;
    height = h;
    width = w;

    Bitmap[] image = new Bitmap[numFrames];
    spritesheet = res;

    for (int i = 0; i < image.length; i++)
    {
        image[i] = Bitmap.createBitmap(spritesheet, i*width, 0, width, height);
    }

    Animation.setFrames(image);
    Animation.setDelay(10);
    startTime = System.nanoTime();

}

public void setJump(boolean b){
    Jump = b;
}

public void update()
{
    long elapsed = (System.nanoTime()-startTime)/1000000;
    if(elapsed>100)
    {
    }
    Animation.update();

    if(Jump){
        dy = (int)(dya+=5.5);

    }
    else{
        dy = (int)(dya+=5.5);
    }

    if(dy>14)dy = 14;
    if(dy>14)dy = -14;

    y += dy*2;
    dy = 0;
}


public void draw(Canvas canvas)
{
    canvas.drawBitmap(Animation.getImage(),x,y,null);
}
public boolean getPlaying(){return playing;}
public void setPlaying(boolean b){playing = b;}
public void resetDYA(){dya = 0;}
}
```

x - character's horizontal position
y - character's vertical position
dx - character's horizontal acceleration
dy - character's vertical acceleration

```
   public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
      if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        if(!deer.getPlaying()) {
            deer.setPlaying(true);
        }
        deer.setJump(true);
        return true;
    }

    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say for sure if this is the only problem because you have other suspicious code but it looks like you jump no matter what.

```
if(Jump){
    dy = (int)(dya+=5.5);
} else {
    dy = (int)(dya+=5.5);
}
```

If `Jump` is `true` you set the vertical acceleration. But you also set the vertical acceleration to the same value if `Jump` is `false`. You also don't show in your code where `Jump` is ever set to `false`.

Another odd bit of code is:

```
if(dy>14)dy = 14;
if(dy>14)dy = -14;
```

Here, if `dy>14` you set it to 14. Then you check `dy>14` immediately after. Of course, this time it's `false`. But because those two conditions are the same the second one will never pass since the one before it ensures it won't. The only other option is they both fail. IOW, you'll never be able to enter the second `if`.

---

***All that aside,*** I'm not sure why you're taking this approach. You can simply rely on physics equations with constant acceleration, give an initial velocity, check for a collision with the ground (or at least the original height), and just let it run. For example:

```
// These are the variables you need.
int x = 200, y0 = 0, y = 0, velocity = 15;
double t = 0.0, gravity = -9.8;

// This is the statement that should run when you update the GUI.
// It is the fundamental equation for motion with constant acceleration.
// The acceleration is the gravitational constant.
y = (int) (y0 + velocity * t + .5 * gravity * t * t);
if (y < 0) {
    y = y0 = 0; 
    //Stop jumping!
    Jump = false; 
} else {
    // Swap the y values.
    y0 = y;
    // Increase the time with the frame rate.
    t += frameRate;
}
// Draw the character using the y value
```

The best part about this is you don't need to worry about when you get to the maximum height because the equation will automatically bring you down. It also looks more natural as if the mechanics are real. Try it out.

---

***A simple Swing example*** that you can play around with. Note that the values are different to deal with the way the components are drawn to the screen. Normally, you would deal with that with transformations but this will do for the task.

```
public class Main {

    static Timer timer;

    Main() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hello sample");
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(550, 550));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel = new MyPanel();
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        timer = new Timer(5, (e) -> panel.repaint());
        timer.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Main::new);
    }

    class MyPanel extends JPanel {
        int x = 200, y0 = 300, y = 0, w = 200, h = 200, v = -8;
        double t = 0.0, gravity = 9.8;
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            y = (int) (y0 + v * t + .5 * gravity * t * t);
            if (y > 300) {
                y = y0 = 300;
                // To prevent it from stopping comment the timer.stop() and 
                // uncomment the t = 0.0 statements.
                //t = 0.0;
                timer.stop();
            } else {
                y0 = y;
                t += .025;
            }
            g.drawOval(x, y, w, h);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried doing if(Jump){
            dy = (int)(dya-=1.1);

        }
        else{
            dy = (int)(dya+=1.1);
        }

        if(dy>14)dy = 14;
        if(dy<-14)dy = -14;

        y += dy*2;
        dy = 0;
But still the charcter goes down and it will go up then the character will be gone

Comment: Please consider the solution I've added to the answer. It will serve you much better than coming up with your own take on physics. @noobkoder

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try it out. I've heard that it's better to make your own 2d games using framework or game engines

Comment: I just tried it out and now its just stays on the ground

Comment: @noobkoder, see the simple example I added. Run it and play around with it.

Comment: Nvm, I figure it out now. Thanks a lot!